# is there limit for IE tool tip character length?

Tags: internet-explorer, tooltip

i'm showing the all USA states in a normal browser tool tip ,FF ,Chrome  works fine its shows all the states name in the tool tip when i check the IE all versions its limits the character after certain length. please help how to resolve this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're reaching a limit to what IE natively supports, the only other option you would have is to avoid using the native tooltip, and instead use an alternative based in either JavaScript for clever CSS. These two methods would remove the limit that you're experiencing with the native attribute.

I would warn you though that if the length of the values you can put into the `title` attribute is causing you problems, you probably should reconsider using the `title` in this way. Tooltips are suppose to be short, and succinct, not verbose and bloated.

Comment: thanks man,i clearly understand that IE native tool tip wont support too long string, now i'm going to use tipsy.js.